# Wit.ai - Getting 2 different intents with confidence = 1 providing the same input text

Tags: wit.ai

I notice the following behaviour yesterday on my english instance of Wit.ai.

For the same input text

"hi, i'd like to book a flight from brussels to nice, leaving next monday in the morning and back in the evening"

I am getting sometimes the intent "intro" with confidence 1, and other times i get the intent "request_price", with conficende also 1

How is that even possible?

Regards
[Example of both responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CRei.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to show what your submitted examples are for `Request_Price`? I would suggest submitting some really small examples in the Understanding tab for both intents, deleting confusing examples from the undesired intent, or perhaps completely deleting the undesired intent and re-adding it with very clear examples (the final suggestion requiring the most work with highest probability of success).